# Backbone.js: Pass params to listenTo

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

How can I retrieve the params when using `listenTo`? For example, I have the following function in a collection:

```
add: function(models, options, firstTime) { 
       //stuff done
}
```

and I have this function in the view:

```
initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addAll);
}
```

The listener is working correctly --*addAll* in the view is being called when *add* is triggered in the collection--, but I don't know how can I retrieve the parameters that `add` used. Is this possible to do? I want to listenTo(), and retrieve the arguments and the values used for the listened function.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get access directly to the argument passed to `add` unless you wrap the function or some similar solution.

Though, if you only want to access the changed attributes, then just check the [`model.change` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed)